# MySQL Syntax Error while adding user with IPv6 Address

Tags: ipv6, mariadb, host

I am trying to create a SQL user on **Server A** so the **Server B** can access SQL server of **Server A** using IPv6 but for some reason I am getting syntax error while running create user command.

The Query I am trying to run:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER ‘dbusr2’@‘2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe24:8266’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘sd6@fs54sd4d’;
```

Getting syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual thatc00::f03c:91ff:fe24:8266’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘sd6@fs54sd4d’' at line 1 use near ':3c
```

Output of `ip -6 addr show` on Server B

```
root@debian:~# ip -6 addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe24:8266/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591996sec preferred_lft 604796sec
    inet6 fe80::f03c:91ff:fe24:8266/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@debian:~#
```

Since I am very new to IPv6 am I missing something here?

Comment: There has been issues with MySQL IPv6 support, so you need to check your MySQL version and see if newer versions fix IPv6 issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are seeing is caused by the *'magic quotes'* you are using, this seems to work

```
CREATE USER 'dbusr2'@'2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe24:8266' IDENTIFIED BY 'sd6@fs54sd4d';
```

Note that this uses standard single quotes.

Comment: silly mistake. new to MacOS :)